# copy sas file from prior version directory to new version directory

Tags: shell-script

How to copy sas file from prior version directory to new version directory in unix script-automatically?

Here prior version = 15_1
      Newer version = 16_0

/data/temp/15_1/

-rwxr-x---   2  mit.sas

/data/temp/16_0

Comment: Hi Jos, what problem are you having with that exactly? The `cp` command can handle that. If you're trying to automate something, please describe that in much more detail (how the version numbers work exactly), and show what you've got so far.

Comment: How to pick the prior version and newer version automatically. I have tried here as using rsync. Here in this directroy version has changing every day. Hence, Here to pick the prior version and newer version is challenge. Thats why I have expect automatically in each timestamp.

Comment: You **need** to provide more details. How are the version numbers generated, what is their general form? And also please show what you have so far. Showing that will help people give you more accurate tips on how to go forward. Don't expect people to write your code for you.

Comment: version is incremental like  10_0,10_1,11_0,11_1........15_0,15_1,16_0

Comment: I have tried--------------                           cd /data/temp/ || exit                                       setopt extendedglob                                        latest_two=(<->_<->(N/nOn[1,2])                       (($#latest_two == 2)) || exit                                     cp -p $latest_two[2]/pt.* $latest_two[1]/

Comment: Please [edit] that in your question to add all that information, and use code formatting for the script (select all the script lines and click on the `{}` button).

Comment: Please read carefully through [this](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and get back here, edit your question based on the recommendations you'll find there and in the comments you've been given on your 4 past identical questions and this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# in bash
shopt -s extglob
cd /data/temp
dirs=$(echo $(ls [1-9]*([0-9])_[0-9] | sort -rn | head -n 2))
# if there are no other files and directories you can use "ls |" in the line above
newer="${dirs% *}"
prior="${dirs#* }"
test -z "$newer" && exit 1
test -z "$prior" && exit 1
cp -p "${prior}/mit.sas" "$newer"/
```

Comment: $ f1=/data/temp/
$ cd $f1
$ dirs=$(echo $(ls [1-9]*([0-9])_[0-9] | sort -rn | head -n 2))
$ newer="${dirs% *}"
$ prior="${dirs#* }"
$ cd $f1$newer
/bin/ksh: /homes/joseprx3/test/16_0::  not found

Comment: Ant thing to be changed in the above code.

Comment: Point 1: I tell you: "in bash". What do you do? Use ksh. If that is a good idea? Make a guess. Point 2: You do not use my code but change it without a good reason. And then you are surprised that it doesn't work. At your level of understanding you **really** should not change the code of others.